# Change the font of figure captions

Tags: fonts, captions

I would like to italicize my figure captions and make them smaller.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

It can be done by loading [the `caption` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/caption) and by choosing options or `\captionsetup`, for instance:

```
\usepackage[font={small,it}]{caption}
```

The caption package provides a lot more feature and is very well documented.

Comment: How can you make it even smaller?

Comment: Instead of `small`, you could choose `footnotesize` or `scriptsize` as property for the `font` option.

Comment: Is there a simple way to get a size in between footnotesize and small? Small is just slightly to big.

Comment: what is the size of `small`? is it relative to the main font size?

Comment: This affect the cls's provided color for the caption, is it possible to prevent the color change?

Answer (score 30):

KOMA-Script provides commands for customizing fonts of certain elements:

- `\setkomafont{element}{commands}`
- `\addtokomafont{element}{commands}`
- `\usekomafont{element}`

The latter can be used for using the configured font for further elements. Among the supported elements are `caption` and `captionlabel`.

So here we could write:

```
\setkomafont{caption}{\footnotesize\itshape}
\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\usekomafont{caption}}
```

[image: figure with smaller italic caption]

Comment: This answer requires familiarity with KOMA-Script. I went through the manual and I still don't understand whether I should use a certain package or what a minimum working example looks like.

Comment: @kon I use scrartcl as document class, and it was very easy to apply. Just put the two lines in the header, no extra package necessary.

Comment: While it’s probably obvious to most, `captionlabel` is “Figure X” (at the left) and `caption` is your actual caption text (to the right).

Answer (score 13):

The [memoir](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/) document class has this baked in.  The provided functionality allows adjustments to the following parameters:

- The font commands used for the caption label (the `Figure x:` part).
- The delimiter that separates the label from the caption.
- The font commands used for the caption text that follows the label.
- The alignment/justification of the caption (left, right, hanging indent, etc)

And much more.  See section 10.6 of the [memoir manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf) for full details.

Memoir also includes support for things such as sub-captions and side-captions.  Chapter 10 of the manual describes all this and much more.