# Figure: how to have "Figure 1.5" in bold

Tags: captions, bold

I'd like to have my figure captions with the word `Figure x.x` in bold, but the rest normal. Ideally, that would be in the header of the file, so that it applies to all the figures in my document.

If it's not possible, is there a way to have a different ... distance to the edge of the page, so it's different from normal text?

So for example, you would have:

```
Normal text blah blah blah.

[actual figure]
Figure 1.5: figure caption
```

I tried to use stuff like `\usepackage[font=bf]{caption}`, but it tells me I don't have `caption.sty` (or `figure.sty` if I replace `caption` by `figure`). I'd be also surprised if we needed a new package only for that. Is there a way to achieve one of the two?

[edit] I've installed the caption package. It might be easier to get this done now.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

The `caption` package provides a lot of functionality and I would recommend to use it. Depending on your LaTeX distribution there a different ways to get the package. You get the files [here](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/caption/), but installing is not trivial. You might want to search 'tex.sx' for 'install package' and pick you system.

You get `Figure x.x` bold with `\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}` when you load the package. If you want to change it later you can use `\captionsetup{labelfont=bf}`. There is more information in a similar question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/822/change-the-font-of-figure-captions).

Comment: How would I change the rest of the caption to be bold as well?

Comment: @pir Replace `labelfont=bf` with just `font=bf`

Comment: Yes! Thank you! Also, just \usepackage{caption} worked for me.