# removing custom text style

Tags: lyx

I wanted to make the font of my figure captions smaller, so I just went from figure to figure and changed the captions using "Text Style -> Customized -> Font Size -> Smaller".

Then I [found out](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/822/change-the-font-of-figure-captions) that there is a much simpler and more general way to achieve the same effect.

But how do I remove all the customized styles that I added manually?

Is it possible to do this automatically in LyX?

Comment: I don't use Lyx but could imagine it is not possible. Open the Lyx file with a standard editor and have a look how your modifications are shown there. Then you could use `regular expressions` to match the entries and modify them.

Comment: If you only care about the output, you don't really need to change back the manually added styles, I think.

Comment: @KevinC: I want to make the font a little smaller, and I think my customized changes might interfere with the global changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know whether it is possible to automate, but to reset the style of text (e.g. size, shape, color, ...), highlight it and use the shortcut `Alt + C, Space`. This will make it revert to the default of whatever environment the text is in.