# Changing figure captions into italic

Tags: captions, italic

Is it possible to change text in figure captions to italic. So this is what I want to get:

[image]

I tried with this code:

```
\usepackage[format=plain,labelfont=bf,up,textfont=it,up]{caption}
```

but word **Figure** is just bold not italic.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! Only for figures or the same for other floats like tables, too?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Change the font of figure captions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/822/5764)

Answer (score 16):

You have a mess in definition of caption ... try something like

```
\usepackage[format=plain,
            labelfont={bf,it},
            textfont=it]{caption}
```

which gives label `Figure` in boldface italic text or

```
\usepackage[format=plain,
            labelfont=it,
            textfont=it]{caption}
```

if you like to have `Figure` only in italic shape. The latter case can be shortly written as:

```
\usepackage[format=plain,
            font=it]{caption}
```

Comment: I assume you could also just us `font=it`?

Comment: @Werner, yes, it could. Fpr consistency I show how the keys for parameters are grouped. I will add this in my answer. Thank you for remain me!

Comment: `textfont=it` also italicises citations, which can be prevented with `\AtEveryCite{\normalfont}`.

Comment: AtEveryCite only available for biblatex. :/