# How to make image captions look different from regular text

Tags: graphics, captions

I've tried various ways of inserting images with captions. Problem is my captions are large (multiple sentences), so they end up looking like regular text. What's a good way to make image captions distinctively dissimilar compared to regular text?

---

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) The question [Change the font of figure captions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/822/106162) may give you some idea of how to change the appearance of caption text.

Comment: You wrote, "Problem is my captions are large (multiple sentences), so they end up looking like regular text." You should ask yourself whether or not you're maybe shoehorning too much information into the captions. Captions usually work best (i.e., they do a good job of  informing the reader quickly what the float is about) if they are short and snappy. Do ask yourself if some part of the information currently placed in the argument of `\caption` constitutes "legend material". Clearly, an informative legend is a *must*. However, is it necessary to force the legend material into the caption?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can:

1) Reduce the font size used for caption, or change the font, with the `caption` package. For instance,

```
\captionsetup{font={footnotesize, sf}, labelfont=bf}
```

will  type the caption in the current sans font, footnotesize, the label being boldface.

2) The default caption width is `\textwidth`. You can use the `measuredfigure` environment, from `threeparttable`, to have  the caption use the width of the figure, if it is significantly smaller than `\textwidth`.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. \captionsetup{font={footnotesize, sf}, labelfont=bf, width=0.8\textwidth}