# Change text of subcaption of figure to italic

Tags: fonts, floats, captions, italic

I am using the `caption` package to create captions and subcaptions (with `\caption*{}`) below my figures. I simply want to change the text format of the subcaption to italic. I have a vague feeling that this should be possible via `\captionsetup{}` but I don't know how. I don't want to use the `subcaptions` package if possible.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % demo is just for the example

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=2cm]{x}
\caption{Test 1}
\caption*{This is the subtext to be placed below the caption of the figure. I want this to be in italic without having to type textit every time} 
\label{fig:test1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe this (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/822/change-the-font-of-figure-captions) answers your question?

Comment: @Excelsior - thank you very much for the link! But this only changes the caption text that follows the label (i.e. "Test 1" in my example). But I want to ONLY change the subcaption text to italic. Any idea how I could do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the `caption` package does not provide the ability to change the style only for the `\caption*` command. The simplest way I can see is to define a new `\subcaption` command in this way:

```
\newcommand{\subcaption}[1]{\caption*{\itshape #1}}
```

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % demo is just for the example

\newcommand{\subcaption}[1]{\caption*{\itshape #1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=2cm]{x}
\caption{Test 1}
\subcaption{This is the subtext to be placed below the caption of the figure. I want this to be in italic without having to type textit every time} 
\label{fig:test1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: works like a charm - thank you very much! Just out  of interest: what is the `#1` in `\newcommand{\subcaption}[1]{\caption*{\itshape #1}}` for?

Comment: `#1`stands for the first (and only) argument of `\subcaption` which is indeed defined as a command with one argument (`[1]`). In other words `\subcation{<text>}` simply expands to `\caption*{\itshape <text>}`, i.e. it substitutes `#1` with the argument passed to `\subcaption`

Comment: thank you - very helpful!